# Will cibil score increase if I file ITR?

Tags: india, credit-score, credit

I have low cibil score. still i ddint file ITR. Will cibil score increase if I file ITR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not matter if you have filed your ITR. It will not have impact of your credit score. If otherwise, people who has TDS, their score should be high. But its not the case.

The following will only impact your score.

- How much you owe to banks?
- How long you are dealing with credits?
- How frequent you are in need of credit?
- And primarily, how many times you have missed your payment?